# Selecting serial and IP, but the rows with the same IP first

Tags: mysql, select, limit, multiple-columns

I have a table `AKA` (Also Known As) to store players names which connects to the server. I have few columns in it: `ID`, `Date`, `IP`, `Serial`, `Country` and `Name`.

I want to select from it just 20 rows, but I need the rows which have the same `IP` as the specified one (player's IP) to be the first (for example: the first 5 rows would have the same `IP` and different `Serial`, and the next will have another `IP`), so if there are 20 rows there will be shown first the rows with the same `IP`.

This is what I made:

```
SELECT * FROM `AKA` WHERE ( `IP` = '%s' OR `Serial` = '%s' ) AND `Country` = '%s' ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 20
```

but I don't know how to sort it by `Date` and same `IP` first, then by `Date`.

I hope that you understand by question, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `AKA` 
WHERE ( `IP` = '%s' OR `Serial` = '%s' ) AND `Country` = '%s' 
ORDER BY `IP` <> '%s' ASC,
         `Serial` <> '%s' ASC,
         `Country` <> '%s' ASC,
         `Date` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```